# Need helping center div block

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have 3 buy cards on my site. Right now there all placed to the left kinda like if you selected text then press format where it will go to the left side, but I want the cards centered in the middle of the screen. Here is a image:

[image]

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <header class="panel-heading">
      <h3>Followers</h3>
      <div class="the-price">$10 <span class="subscript">/ month</span></div>
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr><td>1 Account</td></tr>
        <tr class="active"><td>3 Project</td></tr>
        <tr><td>100K API Access</td></tr>
        <tr class="active"><td>100MB Storage</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Custom Cloud Services</td></tr>
        <tr class="active"><td>Weekly Reports</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default">Sign up now</a></footer>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <header class="panel-heading">
      <h3>Likes</h3>
      <div class="the-price">$20 <span class="subscript">/ month</span></div>
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr><td>2 Account</td></tr>
        <tr class="active"><td>5 Project</td></tr>
        <tr><td>100K API Access</td></tr>
        <tr class="active"><td>200MB Storage</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Custom Cloud Services</td></tr>
        <tr class="active"><td>Weekly Reports</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Sign up now</a></footer>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <header class="panel-heading">
      <h3>Comments</h3>
      <div class="the-price">$35 <span class="subscript">/ month</span></div>
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr><td>5 Account</td></tr>
        <tr class="active"><td>20 Project</td></tr>
        <tr><td>300K API Access</td></tr>
        <tr class="active"><td>500MB Storage</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Custom Cloud Services</td></tr>
        <tr class="active"><td>Weekly Reports</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default">Sign up now</a></footer>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Any suggestions on what should I do to get it to center?
I have tried to add "center to the very top of the code after class= but all that does it make the buy card the size of the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a bootstrap user myself but this does the trick. The bootstrap grid is based on the basis of 12 columns so when you specified "col-md-3" thats actually 3/12 or 25% not "col-md-4" which is 33%". The trick is we dont want the row to be full width so I added a class called medium-row which has a max-width of 960px and some auto margins.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row medium-row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.medium-row {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And a codepen to see this working http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJPydY

Comment: I shouldn't have to answer that question but if you want to be really incorrect then you can add to your row <div class="row" style="max-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;">

If your asking how to add css to a website you need to do some reading first.

Comment: I don't want to drag the question but that's one thing I don't know. Where at do I edit the CSS. My main.css seems really unorganized.

Comment: If you know where your main.css file is then add it at anywhere in there if your positive that your main.css file is the one being loaded

Comment: So how should i format the HTML with my HTML, could you add it to the code as a example. I added the CSS tho.

Comment: I copied your exact HTML i just changed the col-md-3 to col-md-4. I also provided a codepen showing your exact html. I also explained in my answer why I did this.

Comment: Your question is not related to the footer of your website which we cannot see. If the answer is correct please mark it as correct. The changes I have made should have no effect on your footer. If you are referring to the footer of the panel it should also have no effect on that as well.

Comment: Sorry about that, I deleted the </selection>. Thanks, I understand now.

Comment: Do you have a skype I could contact you about a couple problems I need help with?

Comment: You can mark the question as complete that would be your first step.

Answer (score -1):

My two cents, nothing centers quite like a table tag. Its very unpopular, but it tends to work best in a pinch. Try it out:

```css
td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
        <td class="panel panel-default">
            <header class="panel-heading">
                 <h3>Followers</h3>

                <div class="the-price">$10 <span class="subscript">/ month</span>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1 Account</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td>3 Project</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>100K API Access</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td>100MB Storage</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Custom Cloud Services</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td>Weekly Reports</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <footer class="panel-footer"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default">Sign up now</a>
            </footer>
        </td>
        <td class="panel panel-primary">
            <header class="panel-heading">
                 <h3>Likes</h3>

                <div class="the-price">$20 <span class="subscript">/ month</span>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2 Account</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td>5 Project</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>100K API Access</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td>200MB Storage</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Custom Cloud Services</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td>Weekly Reports</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <footer class="panel-footer"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Sign up now</a>
            </footer>
        </td>
        <td class="panel panel-default">
            <header class="panel-heading">
                 <h3>Comments</h3>

                <div class="the-price">$35 <span class="subscript">/ month</span>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>5 Account</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td>20 Project</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300K API Access</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td>500MB Storage</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Custom Cloud Services</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td>Weekly Reports</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <footer class="panel-footer"><a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default">Sign up now</a>
            </footer>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It centered the 3 in the middle touching and removed my whole footer

Comment: OK I added cellspacing="10" to the table tag at the top, this number can be increased for more space between the buy options. I don't see a footer in your provided html however...